# joomla pagination getListFooter on front-end not work

Tags: joomla, pagination

i learn developt component base on tutorial at http://docs.joomla.org/ , i got problem at pagination ,click page 1,2,3... not work ,

here are my code :
com_bet/models/test.php:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.component.modellist');
class BetModelTest extends JModelList{      
    protected function getListQuery(){      
        $db=JFactory::getDbo();
        $query=$db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*')->from('#__member');     
        return $query;
    }   
}
```

com_bet/views/test/view.html.php

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');
class BetViewTest extends JViewLegacy{
    function display($tpl=null){        
        $items=$this->get('Items');
        $pagination=$this->get('Pagination');
        $this->items=$items;
        $this->pagination=$pagination;
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

com_bet/views/test/tmpl/default.php:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>
<form action="index.php?option=com_bet&view=test" method="post">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Funds</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <?php foreach ($this->items as $item){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item->id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->username;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->pass;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->funds;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>   
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='4'><?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter();?></td>
    </tr>
<tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

i watch in chrome inspect element , it show "Cannot read property 'limitstart' of undefined " like pic behind :
http://i1119.photobucket.com/albums/k623/helbros/joomla.png

[image: Chrome - Inspect Element]

help me thank very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `id` attribute to your form, also you need hidden field with name `limitstart` in your form. Currently javascript is looking for form with id `adminForm` and cannot find it.

To update default limit, you can extend your `Model` by adding method `populateState`, which should look like this:

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null) {
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();

  $limit = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('global.list.limit', 'limit', $app->getCfg('list_limit'), 'uint');
  $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);
  // As you can see if no limit is set, it gets it from default value of config, 
  // but you can replace $app->getCfg('list_limit') by any integer you want to 
  // override default limit value

  $limitstart = $app->input->get('limitstart', 0, 'uint');
  $this->setState('list.start', $limitstart);

  $limitstart = $app->input->get('limitstart', 0, 'uint');
  $this->setState('list.start', $limitstart); 
}
```

Comment: thanks u, i add 2 attribute `name="adminForm"` `id="adminForm"` to tag <form> and now it work perfectly . but i have one more problem about display record on table, it always display 20 record in the first time  when load web page, how to change that .Somebody said change $limit value in code ,but i don't know where to change that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question (more than a year ago), but I was having the same problem on Joomla 3 - that is, I could get pagination to work on the front-end with some effort, but changing the number of list elements displayed did not work. I finally figured it out.

The problem was that the select limitbox in both the filter and the pagination had a name of "limit" and not "list[limit]". Editing the HTML to the latter made it work.

How to make it work in the code:
1. You must have a filter, so a filter_VIEW.xml file in /models/form with a fieldlist "list" and a field "limit" type "limitbox" (look at com_users for an example).
2. You must invoke the filter in the view with

```
JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', array('view' => $this, 'options' => array('filtersHidden' =>$hidden)));
```

This will give you a limitbox in the filter area (you don't need any other filters).
3. To get rid of the non-functioning limitbox in the pagination area, use CSS to set the class "limit" to "display:none;"

I hope this helps others. It took me quite a while to figure this out.